# Hibernateについて

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate5.2.17.Finalをダウンロードしました。しかしどのJARファイルを選べばいいのかわかりません。

インターネット上の日本語のサイトはバージョンが古いものが多く、私が落としたzipファイルにはないものばかりで困っています。

とりあえずrequiredフォルダに含まれるものは全部必要でしょうか？

Comment: アプリの依存関係次第なので、それだけの情報では回答ができません。もう少し具体的にどのような手順で何を実現しようとしているかを書いていただいた方がいいかと思います。とりあえず全て入れておけば、動くと思いますが（他のライブラリとの競合などがなければ）。

Answer (score 1):

> とりあえずrequiredフォルダに含まれるものは全部必要でしょうか？

その通りです。

---

documentationディレクトリにドキュメントが展開されていると思います。
同じものがwebでも参照できますが、
quickstartの[1.2. Release Bundle Downloads](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#_release_bundle_downloads)節に説明があります。

> The lib/required/ directory contains the hibernate-core jar and all of its dependencies. All of these jars are required to be available on your classpath no matter which features of Hibernate are being used.

---

> インターネット上の日本語のサイトはバージョンが古いものが多く

最近はMavenやGradleといったビルド管理ツールを用いるため、必要となる依存ライブラリ(jarファイル)をいちいち意識しないことが大半になったのも、古い説明しか無い一因であるかなと考えます。